# C#: How do I check the value of a field before Wizard's next step? (NextButtonClick)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

When the user clicks to "Continue" after the Wizard's first step I would like check that the value (selected index) of MyRadioBtn is 1. If not, then open a panel and do not proceed to Step 2 of the wizard.

The problem I'm having is the "MyRadioBtn.SelectedIndex" conditional never returns a value of 1.

Front-end:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="MyRadioBtn" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
     <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex == 0)
    {
        if (MyRadioBtn.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            //Stop the user from moving on to step 2
            e.Cancel = true;
            //Show the user a panel
            WarningPanel.Visible = true;
        }
        else {
           //Continue to STEP 2
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified if the post back is being fired with a network tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to fire a postbkack after the user selects an item from de DropDownList? If not, change `AutoPostBack="True"` to `AutoPostBack="False"`

Comment: That was it. I missed the fact that the AutoPostBack value wasn't set (and therefore was always "false"). Thanks!